# Ajax.ActionLink Pop-Up not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am  using Asp.net-mvc 2.0, while i am going to give ajax.actionlink pop to call a new page actionresult i am not able to call pop-up, it thrown an error.

My sample code:-

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("GetFuncao", "GetFuncao?height=155&width=300&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&modal=true", "Funcao", new { ID = Model.ID_Sistema },
    new AjaxOptions { }, new { @class = "thickbox", id = "thickbox", title="Cadastro de Sistemas" })%>
```

While I am using this code , following error occurred,

"**A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).**"

Can you help me to fix this issue. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass query string parameters in the `routeValues` not with the action name, like this:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink(
    "GetFuncao", 
    "GetFuncao", 
    "Funcao", 
    new { 
        ID = Model.ID_Sistema,
        height = "155",
        width = "300",
        inlineId = "hiddenModalContent",
        modal = "true"
    }, 
    new AjaxOptions { }, 
    new { @class = "thickbox", id = "thickbox", title="Cadastro de Sistemas" }
)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your route values into the correct place, i.e.

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("GetFuncao", "GetFuncao", "Funcao", new { ID = Model.ID_Sistema, height=155, width=300, inlineId="hiddenModelContent", modal = true },
    new AjaxOptions { }, new { @class = "thickbox", id = "thickbox", title="Cadastro de Sistemas" })%>
```